# ReFS Scrubbing of User Data

Tags: refs

[According to this](http://www.refs-data-recovery.com/new-features-in-refs.aspx) ReFS requires checksumming all file system metadata. It can checksum user data, but it is not the default option.

In ReFS, if integrity streams are enabled (Mirrored Storage Space), is user data checksummed?

Comment: My quick tests under Win2012R2 show, that user data (file content) is not checksummed by default on plain volumes, but is checksummed on Storage Spaces volumes (both simple and mirror types).

Answer (score 2):

Enabling integrity streams causes both user data and the filesystem metadata to be checksummed (reference [Resilient File System Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831724.aspx)). Otherwise, just filesystem metadata is checksummed.

The `integrity.exe` tool, that can be used to toggle integrity on/off for empty files, seems to be very poorly documented by Microsoft. I haven't actually had occasion to use ReFS in production yet, so I don't have any personal experience to share with you.

Comment: You have to enable integrity on a file by file basis?

Answer (score 0):

By default, user data checksums are **not** enabled, even when using Storage Spaces.

To enable user data checksums on ReFS, run the following in an administrator PowerShell prompt:

`ls D:\ -r | Set-FileIntegrity -Enable $TRUE`

(Where `D:\` is an ReFS directory or file)

To check if user data checksums are enabled:

`Get-FileIntegrity D:\`

(Again, where `D:\` is a ReFS directory or file)

Sources:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/storage/set-fileintegrity
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/storage/get-fileintegrity